# how to slice a string in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

1

```
 var userQuestion = '10+5-√x+96';
```

2

```
 var userQuestion = '10+5-√x+96-√x-2+√x';
```

i am expecting to get the value between square root and the next operator in the string and grouping them into different strings

how can i slice the string √x if i don't know it's index in dart.

and make other strings with respect to the number of √x in the string

eg in 1 i want a string slice that will create

```
var squareRoot = '√x';
```

and in 2 i want to get something like this

```
var squareRoot = '√x';
var squareRoot1 = '√x';
var squareRoot2 = '√x';
```

Comment: you want to extract all √x from string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the squareroots including whatever comes after, until you hit an operator, then this should do the trick:

```
var userQuestion = '10+5-√x+96-√y-2+√5/√123*√256';
var regexp = RegExp(r'(√[\w\d]+)[+\-*/]?');
var matches = regexp.allMatches(userQuestion);
var squareRoots = matches.map((e) => e.group(1)).toList();
print(squareRoots);
```

Will print:

```
[√x, √y, √5, √123, √256]
```

There is obviously no way to declare variables with names as you did if it is an unknown number of square roots, so you'll have to use a `List<String>` that hold your strings, as I did above.